# How to remove characters which are coming after point?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove characters which are coming after point. There are 6 characters after point. It is not changing.

***Input (String) :***

```
52.01317215 1121.53601074 1049.63146973 1540.70495605
517.47277832 85.62935638 553.46118164 106.97449493
1.70361996 550.58435059 159.12145996 714.25854492
```

***Output (String) (what i want):***

```
52 1121 1049 1540
517 85 553 106
1 550 159 714
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: `int(52.01317215)`

Comment: @Salih, are they in format of int stored in a variable or string stored in a variable ?

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan i ve updated. Sorry for missing information.

Comment: `map(int, input().split())` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is a multiline string and your output should be another multiline string with all the decimal parts removed, you could use a regex:

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"\.\d+", "", mystring)

>>> print(result)
52 1121 1049 1540
517 85 553 106
1 550 159 714
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below as a example, you should here use **split firstly to get into the string through for loop** and then again you need to use split to get it **separated with .**

```
    s="52.01317215 1121.53601074 1049.63146973 1540.70495605 517.47277832 
     85.62935638 553.46118164 106.97449493 1.70361996 550.58435059 
     159.12145996 714.25854492"
    for s1 in s.split(" "):
        print(s1.split(".")[0])
```

And your solution would look like

> 52 1121 1049 1540 517 85 553 106 1 550 159 714

Comment: @SalihKaragoz, it should work fine, I posted it with the output after executing the code.

Answer (score 1):

One way is through regex:

```
s = """
52.01317215 1121.53601074 1049.63146973 1540.70495605
517.47277832 85.62935638 553.46118164 106.97449493
1.70361996 550.58435059 159.12145996 714.25854492
"""
import re
final_data = map(int, re.findall("\d+(?=\.)", s))
```

Output:

```
[52, 1121, 1049, 1540, 517, 85, 553, 106, 1, 550, 159, 714]
```

If you do not want the final strings casted to integers, you can try this:

```
new_data = [b for b in [re.findall("\d+(?=\.)", i) for i in s.split("\n")] if b]
```

Output:

```
[['52', '1121', '1049', '1540'], ['517', '85', '553', '106'], ['1', '550', '159', '714']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '''52.01317215 1121.53601074 1049.63146973 1540.70495605
517.47277832 85.62935638 553.46118164 106.97449493
1.70361996 550.58435059 159.12145996 714.25854492'''

s2 = ''
use_char = True
for c in s:
    if c == '.':
        use_char = False
    elif c == ' ':
        use_char = True
    if use_char:
        s2 += c
print(s2)
```

results in:

```
52 1121 1049 1540 85 553 106 550 159 714
```

Comment: If you like my answer it would be nice if you could vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
str="""52.01317215 1121.53601074 1049.63146973 1540.70495605 
517.47277832 85.62935638 553.46118164 106.97449493 
1.70361996 550.58435059 159.12145996 714.25854492"""
for i in str.split():
    print '%d' % float(i)
```

Comment: @Sandeep: for i in str_split:
    print(int(float(i)))
would work better.

Answer (score 0):

Python-3.9 code

This can also be solved with ListComprehension

Just modifying Sandeep's code here ,

```
listOfFloats = """52.01317215 1121.53601074 1049.63146973 1540.70495605 
517.47277832 85.62935638 553.46118164 106.97449493 
1.70361996 550.58435059 159.12145996 714.25854492"""

result = [int(float(i)) for i in listOfFloats.split()]

print(result)
```